# How to change drawing line size in TeeChart

Tags: c#, winforms, teechart

I am working with TeeChart fro .net, I would like to increase the size of drawing line in the chart. presently it is drawing very thin line which is not visible for all people. How to increase size of drawing line in TeeChart.

I have attached a simple chart image from my application. I would like to draw the line with more or equal size to axis lines. presently it seems drawing line size less that axis line size. I mean i want to draw line more thick.

2) How to assign axis scale more reliably, i mean presently if i have axis minimum and maximum values from 0 to 6, then it is showing on the axis like 0,2,4,6. I would like to see like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 like that i mean with 1 scale increment. Please help me with the above two things.

1) How to increase drawing line size?
2) How to assign scale of axis more convenient?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The chart's features mention support for Csharp .NET charting control.
http://www.steema.com/teechart/net

Microsoft has pages with information about the chart controls:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632.aspx

Looks like you will find how to do the things you want there.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How to increase drawing line size?

You can set Line or FastLine Pen.Width like this:

```
  line1.LinePen.Width = tChart1.Axes.Left.AxisPen.Width;
```

> 2) How to assign scale of axis more convenient?

TeeChart will automatically set axis scales to the minimum increment possible provided labels don't overlap. To get a fixed axis increment you should set axis Increment property. Labels won't be allowed to overlap though.

```
  tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Increment = 1;
```

For more information on axis settings please read tutorial 4. Tutorials can be found at TeeChart's program group.